# How to get all cms blocks ids where "is_slider" = true?

Tags: collection, magento1.9.2.3

Modyfying current slider system to make it a little bit more autonomous as in it's original form I must manually remove code from list if specific products is already gone or promotion is over so I added additional attribute into table "is_slider", "start_date" and "end_date" but my collection does not work.
What I've done wrong ?

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
      ->addFieldToFilter('is_slider', '1')
      ->getAllIds()
      ;
```

Of course this code should select only ids where "is_slider" is true, regardless what date is but it is not important for now.

How to get only those Ids where "is_slider" = true?

OMG I'm blind ......
Yes of course it does work after I changed it from "page" to "block"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Mage::getModel('cms/page')` CMS Pages model.

Use `Mage::getModel('cms/block')` Static block model.

Comment: Thank you Pankaj, silly me, how could I not see this ? Thank you

Comment: Glad it worked for you. please accept the  answer so that it will helpful for others